# Redefining point shapefiles in MXD that have no projection and are located in different folders using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, layers

```
    # Script to use Layers in MXD source file paths to locate and redefine projections

import arcpy, glob, os, sys, arcgisscripting
from arcpy import env, mapping
path = os.getcwd()
env.workspace = path
env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("N:\MXDs\_ThomaKL\MXD GPS Valves\GPS_Shapefile_Paths.mxd")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        print lyr.dataSource

print 'Reading files from ' + lyr.dataSource
os.chdir(path)
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(103133)

x=0
z=x+1
NoProjCount=0
FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers()
for File in FileList:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(File)
    SR = desc.spatialReference
    if SR.name == "Unknown":
        print "Projection of " + str(File) + " is " + SR.name + " so defining projection."
        f = open('NoProjection.txt', 'a')
        f.write(str(File)+"\n")
        f.close()
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(File, sr) 
        NoProjCount=NoProjCount+1
    else:    
        print File + " is projected " + str(SR.name)
```

I get this after I run the Script
[image]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\MXDs_ThomaKL\MXD GPS Valves\DefineProjWDTest", line 22, in 
    FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
TypeError: ListLayers() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

> NoProjection.txt shows a list of featureclasses that is in the folder where the featureclasses is Located.

I have a python script that I have been working on were the script goes into a MXD that has several shapefiles that are in different locations on my network.  Again I am trying to use the location of the shapefiles in the MXD to tell python where to look for them and then redefine their projections..  I feel like I am very close but I have hit a road block with it and I was wondering if anyone could help me finish this to get it to work..

**Update**

```
    # Script to use Layers in MXD source file paths to locate and redefine projections

import arcpy, glob, os, sys, arcgisscripting

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("N:\MXDs\_ThomaKL\MXD GPS Valves\GPS_Shapefile_Paths.mxd")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        print lyr.dataSource

from arcpy import env, mapping
path = lyr.dataSource
env.workspace = path
env.overwriteOutput = True

print 'Reading files from ' + path

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(103133)

x=0
z=x+1
NoProjCount=0
FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(lyr)
for lyr in FileList:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
    SR = desc.spatialReference
    if SR.name == "Unknown":
        print "Projection of " + str(lyr) + " is " + SR.name + " so defining projection."
        f = open('NoProjection.txt', 'a')
        f.write(str(lyr)+"\n")
        f.close()
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(lyr, sr) 
        NoProjCount=NoProjCount+1
    else:    
        print lyr + " is projected " + str(SR.name)
```

I realized i had some pieces ordered wrong so I decided to make some changes to my original code, good news is that it worked the bad news is that it only worked on the very last layer in the MXD, so all the other layers in the MXD still showed up with "no projection".  it doesn't give me any errors, but again i am trying to get it to go through the list of layers in the folders and define their projections, as i said it only does the very last one that it reads not the entire list.

Comment: That looks fine, are the projections not being set? What's in NoProjection.txt?

Comment: You say "I have hit a road block" but you have not told us what that road block is (error message or other symptoms), nor asked a specific question.  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson well that is good, it does seem to run okay, as for the NoProjection.txt, I can not find the txt file to look at it, I wondering i might need to place the script file in the folder with the MXD for it to actually define the projections of the shapefiles?  I just thought about that after you said that, i moved the file for safety.  I'll add a image of the error I get.

Comment: @PolyGeo you are right sorry let me get that image of the Python Shell.

Comment: @PolyGeo,  As you said I am New to this website format, I will take the tour to better navigate it and ask questions.  so as you can see the script doesn't run well with the arcpy.mapping.ListLayers() on Line22. there seems to be something going on with an argument.  I am also still learning on Python but I am trying my best.

Comment: You haven't included a full path for NoProjections.txt so it will be where the command window starts... possibly put in a full path like 'c:\\NoProj.txt' to make it easier to find. Your 2nd ListLayers needs an argument (same as first) or even better still list your layers to a variable then iterate that twice: AllLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) then iterate for lyr in AllLayers and for File in AllLayers.

Comment: Please include errors as text rather than pictures so that they can become available to future searches.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thank you both for the help I will make the necessary corrections and get back with you guys.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that this iterates fine through multiple shapefiles until it gets to the last ...\Valve.shp file?  As others have suggested, please post the contents of NoProjection.txt to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: @MaryBeth the goal is that I want the script to go to each file folder of the shapefile's location that is located in the MXD and then define the projection of those shapefiles.

Comment: The NoProjection.txt file is created when it locates the shapefiles with Unknown Status in the MXD all the file has inside is a list of the Shapefiles that is found.

Comment: I am also going to change the part of the code that says (prjFile=r'C:\\Python27\\Oklahoma_StatePlane_83N_FIPS_3501.prj') to (sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(103133).  I am adapting the define projection portion of this script from another script that I use for files that are located in the same WorkingDirectory as the MXD.

Comment: @MaryBeth the script works on the first part where it goes through the MXD and list the file paths of all the shapefiles in the MXD its when I want it to use those file paths to locate those shapefiles with undefined or unknown projection status that it gives me the error, know that I changed the  script to set the projection using the (sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(103133) it says the error is on line 22.

Comment: I think it would result in cleaner Q&A (remember that this is not a discussion forum) if you were to start a new question for the new place that you are stuck and back your last few updates out of this question. Although we are helping you too our first priority for any question is always the lasting record that makes life easier for all those that come looking for the same answer in years to come. Keeping things highly readable is therefore important.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake here, that I think manifests itself as that error:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("N:\MXDs\_ThomaKL\MXD GPS Valves\GPS_Shapefile_Paths.mxd")
```

which should be:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"N:\MXDs\_ThomaKL\MXD GPS Valves\GPS_Shapefile_Paths.mxd")
```

or

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("N:\\MXDs\\_ThomaKL\\MXD GPS Valves\\GPS_Shapefile_Paths.mxd")
```

or

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("N:/MXDs/_ThomaKL/MXD GPS Valves/GPS_Shapefile_Paths.mxd")
```

I am also not so sure about the underscore in the `_ThomaKL` folder name.  If the above does not work try renaming that folder and changing your code to match.

Comment: The error is on line FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers() which should be FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd), you are right about the raw paths and escape characters though.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson From the output you are right; I wonder how the code (if run precisely as presented) got that far?

Comment: It ran through the first loop (listlayers correct) just fine but when it got to the 2nd it fell over on the missing parameter. Theoretically, you're right, it shouldn't have even got that far due to escape characters, I think though it's just luck as \M and \G aren't escape characters so were passed as-is. It would have been a different story if it was a path like d:\Toby\.. as \T is TAB.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson yes I did try changing the FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers() to FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) and that gave me an error on Line 24 because I have "for File in FileList:" and desc =  arcpy.Describe(File).  I am thinking that needs to be changed to mxd as well as the parts that reference (File) after that.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers ()` requires an argument. As per its [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm) it requires the map document object (or a layer object) as its input.

```
arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd)
```